# Bash handle multiple user menu choices with same variables

Tags: bash, shell

I currently have script which handles user choice based on presented menu and depending on what option is selected, variables are assigned values and some variables are assigned values based on if conditions. Then some functions are called using that variables. Simplified logic is here

```
PS3='Please make your choice'
options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Quit")
COLUMNS=0
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Option 1")
            varA="Value1"
            varB="Text1"

            if something; then
              varC="String1" 
            else
              varC="String2"
            fi 
            break
            ;;

        "Option 2")
            varA="Value2"
            varB="Text2"
            break
            ;;
        
        "Quit")
            exit 0
            ;;

        *)
            echo $red "Invalid option $REPLY" $txtreset;;
    esac

prepare "${varA}" "${varB}"
update "${varA}" "${varB}" "${varC}"
```

So this logic allows one user choice and then processing happens based on that choice.

Is it possible to capture multiple users choices, like Option 1 and Option 2 for example and then run further script steps in a loop twice. Once using variable values from 1st choice and second time using variable values from 2nd choice.?

Comment: Possible, but messy and easy to get wrong. What about running the `prepare` and `update` steps inside of the `select` loop?

Comment: Problem is, that I provided kind of simplified example, in reality there is much more steps out there, so I hoped I can avoid just duplicating that bunch of code multiple times.

Comment: @GordonDavisson any ideas for that probably messy solution or any others?